# put text on div with out affecting hover

Tags: html, css, video, text, hover

I just tried putting text over my video. The video autostarts when hovering it. With the Text on it the hover is "disabled". Is there any option to display the text without effecting the hover? Text is absolute.

I use a js to start the video. The Text is in a div on top.

```
    window.onload = function() { //executes this code after the DOM loads
   //--- this is the selector element. Feel free to change this if you don't want all video objects targeted.
  const vids = document.getElementsByTagName(`video`)

   //--- Now we loop over all of the selected elements and add event listeners
  for (let i = 0; i < vids.length; i++) {
    vids[i].addEventListener( `mouseover`, function(e) { 
      vids[i].play()
    })
    vids[i].addEventListener( `mouseout`, function(e) {
      vids[i].pause()
    })
  }
}
```

[Image from Webinspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVO2P.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :) You'd probably need to modify your `onhover` functionality to also include the hover of the text, but we can't know without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can add the two following css properties to the text object so that the user cannot interact with them.

```
.text-class {
    user-select: none;
    pointer-events: none; 
}
```

If you still want the users to be able to select the text, say if copy & pasting the text is important you can just do.

```
.text-class {
    pointer-events: none; 
}
```